# Failed to Load Resource In Production but Not Locally

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on a Django project and I have it deployed on pythonanywhere.com.  In my project, I am using Django Jsignature which works fine on my local machine.  In production, however, when I load the particular template, I get this error in my console - 'myurl' portion is not the real url.

````
https://myurl.com/static/js/jSignature.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)```
````

So I don't get this locally, but do in Production. Can anyone suggest for me where to start on this? I'm not even really sure where to begin, it's my first time deploying anything.

**EDIT**

you can see the details of django jsignature here: https://pypi.org/project/django-jsignature/

the `{{form.media}}` should load this script.

**UPDATE 2**
This is no longer working locally either.  Here are the error in my console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token jSignature.min.js:70
```

```
Uncaught TypeError:
$(...).jSignature is not a function
```

Comment: This is a static js file? Are you calling it with the `static` tag? Where are you hosting your static files?

Comment: @leelum1 I do not have this file in my static files - but I'm a bit confused about that myself.  if you see the link I added to the question above, the ```{{form.media}}``` tag loads this script in with ```src="/static/js/jSignature.min.js```.  But I do not have that file in my static files folder, yet it works locally.

Comment: is it pulling that script from your static folder locally? You may need to run a `collectstatic`

Comment: interestingly I cleared my browser history and now it's not working locally either - great

Comment: Have you run the collectstatic management command?

Comment: @GilesThomas no I have not - but now I'm not even having it work locally. I am getting an error in my console that jsignature is not a function.  Will add to the question. If there is a syntax error in the file how am I supposed to fix that, I don't even have it saved locally.

Comment: That's very weird!  What is there at line 70 (where you have that syntax error) when you view source on the page?